# Background of div next to floating image is shown behind image?

Tags: html, css

I have an image and 2 divs. The image floats to the left, and the divs have some background color. For some reason the background of the divs is shown behind the image (it's partly transparent). The text in the div is however shown properly, next to the image.

```css
img {
  float: left;
}

div > div {
 background-color: rgb(240, 128, 48);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://pokeapi.co/media/sprites/pokemon/141.png"/>
  <div>Kabutops</div>
  <div>Some info</div>
</div>
```

I would expect that the orange background only starts just right of the image, rather than under it.

Why does this happen? And can it be fixed with only css?

Comment: You can try to use  margin-left: 96px; on your div > div style. But, I think z-index is better solution :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does this happen?

Because that’s how `float` works.

Only inline content such as text, other image, spans, … is *floated around* the image – block elements per se are not.

But there’s an easy fix to that: Make them establish their own *block formatting context* – which f.e. `overflow:hidden` can achieve – then they will be floated around the image as well.

```css
img {
  float: left;
}

div > div {
    overflow: hidden;
 background-color: rgb(240, 128, 48);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://pokeapi.co/media/sprites/pokemon/141.png"/>
  <div>Kabutops</div>
  <div>Some info</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Using `overflow: hidden;` worked like a charm :D

Answer (score 1):

```css
.test {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;

}
.text {
  flex:2;
 background-color: rgb(240, 128, 48);
}
```

```html
<div class="test">

  <img src="http://pokeapi.co/media/sprites/pokemon/141.png"/>
  <div class="text">
  <p>Kabutops</p>
  <p>Some info</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

is this what you looking for:

Comment: Oh, this isn't bad either. Thanks! But what CBroe said is exactly what I was looking for.